# display view of another controller MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm starting to develope in .NET and I have some questions.

I've created a view which uploads images to Azure. This view is included in a Controller called Document.

What I want is to display this view in another controller view. The view works perfectly alone, but when I try to reference it it gives me an error which I still don't know how to solve.

This is the view "Upload.cshtml"

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Documento", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" />
    }
</p>

<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <img src="@item" alt="images" width="100" height="100" />
            <a id="@item" href="#" onclick="deleteImage('@item');">Delete</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<script type="text/jscript">
    //get file size
    function deleteImage(item) {
        try {
            var url = "/Documento/DeleteImage";

            $.post(url, { Name: item }, function (data) {
                window.location.href = "/Documento/Upload";
                alert(data);
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("Error is :" + e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is how I try to invoke the view from another Controller Index view:

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Documento/Upload.cshtml");
@RenderBody();
```

And the error I get is because of the "@foreach(var item in Model)" sentence.

How should I do this?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I've been out. When I call the Upload method I would like to also get the url and add it to my Document.Url so I can create a new Document. I think once I achieve that I'm going to be able to do the things you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing your model at the top of your view.  Something like this:

@model MyProject.Models.MyModel

Secondly your foreach loop needs a IEnumerable type.  Is your model IEnumerable or @Model.SomeIEnumerable?

Lastly, whatever @item is in your loop should have seperate properties for your img src and anchor id attributes.

Either your code displayed isn't complete or you have a model issue.  Here is any example of how to do what I think you are looking for.

View Model

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string ProductId {get;set;}
  public string ProductSrc {get;set;}
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
<ul>
@foreach(item in Model)
{
 <li>
   <img src="@item.ProductSrc" />
   <a id="@item.ProductId">Delete</>
 </li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the view to the `Views/Shared` folder instead. Then it will be available to all controllers without having to do anything special.

Also your view obviously expects a model to be passed in, so you have to do that from both controllers using the view.

In the controller that works I assume you have something like

```
return View("Upload", model);
```

or just

```
return View(model);
```

if you're action is named `Upload`. In the new action that is to use the same view, you have to create the model object and pass it to the view too.